# How to use token fetched from ms teams (using SSO in tabs) for the logged in user to login to an application that has its own msal authentication

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL to authenticate users using azure ad and its working fine in browser, but when I create a ms teams app using app studio of ms teams . it is able to fetch the token for logged in user and there after if I redirect to my application which have its own authentication mechanism . I am not getting any idea about how to use this token to get the user authenticated in my application.

Comment: Could you please refer below Tab SSO sample :
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso

Comment: This samples fetches me out the assertion token for the logged in user.. but I want to use this assertion token in a third application that is using msal and have its own authentication mechanishm with azure ad.

Comment: Can you please check with OAuth provider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-oauth-provider